# Power distribution PCB and Li-po batteries

Tags: pcb, lipo, step-down

I am hoping to work on a project over the summer and it requires a decent bit of current. I ended up going with two [7.4 V, 5400 mAh](https://www.amazon.ca/Zeee-5200mAh-Battery-Vehicles-Airplane/dp/B08B181YNH/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8) batteries and I was planning on running them in parallel.

With this I want to power a Raspberry Pi and a [servo driver](https://www.amazon.ca/HiLetgo-PCA9685-Channel-12-Bit-Arduino/dp/B01D1D0CX2/ref=asc_df_B01D1D0CX2/?tag=googleshopc0c-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=683126290304&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=4277816423089346184&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9000801&hvtargid=pla-439629573722&psc=1&mcid=b730fd926b6b3d35bf6900734ff8714a&gad_source=1), but before powering their respective devices I was going to put in a buck step-down converter in order to meet the powering requirements for both devices.

As the wiring from the batteries would cause a lot of clutter I decided that a PCB might be a good idea. However, I am little confused, as there is no T Deans connector to go on the PCB.

Is it a good idea to just cut the wire before the T Deans connector and solder the connections together before going into PCB (plug into a suitable female connector) where I can draw traces to their respective step down regulator? Are there things I should take into consideration as in gauge of the wire, and is it worth the hassle? Or should I just deal with the clutter?

I would have provided a schematic, but my main concern is how to connect the Li-po battery to the PCB, and if it good idea to do that with this type of battery.